# Slice string at last digit in Python

Tags: python, regex, string

So I have strings with a date somewhere in the middle, like `111_Joe_Smith_2010_Assessment` and I want to truncate them such that they become something like `111_Joe_Smith_2010`. The code that I thought would work is

```
reverseString = currentString[::-1]
stripper = re.search('\d', reverseString)
```

But for some reason this doesn't always give me the right result. Most of the time it does, but every now and then, it will output a string that looks like `111_Joe_Smith_2010_A`.

If anyone knows what's wrong with this, it would be super helpful!

Comment: Will the date you want always be preceded by and followed by an underscore?

Comment: Yes if it does just split and join removing the last one

Comment: @E.Serra no need to join `my_string.rsplit("_", 1)[0]` (but assumes no '111_Bob_Smith_2010_Test_assessment' like test cases)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `re.sub` and `$` to match and substitute alphabetical characters 
 and underscores until the end of the string:

```
import re
d = ['111_Joe_Smith_2010_Assessment', '111_Bob_Smith_2010_Test_assessment']
new_s = [re.sub('[a-zA-Z_]+$', '', i) for i in d]
```

Output:

```
['111_Joe_Smith_2010', '111_Bob_Smith_2010']
```

Answer (score 2):

You could strip non-digit characters from the end of the string using [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html#re.sub) like this:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'\D+$', '', '111_Joe_Smith_2010_Assessment')
'111_Joe_Smith_2010'
```

For your input format you could also do it with a simple loop:

```
>>> s = '111_Joe_Smith_2010_Assessment'
>>> i = len(s) - 1
>>> while not s[i].isdigit():
...     i -= 1
... 
>>> s[:i+1]
'111_Joe_Smith_2010'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following approach:

```
def clean_names():
    names = ['111_Joe_Smith_2010_Assessment', '111_Bob_Smith_2010_Test_assessment']
    for name in names:
        while not name[-1].isdigit():
            name = name[:-1]
        print(name)
```

Comment: It may solve OP problem but not an efficient approach though. Imagine if there is no digit in the string still it will iterate over all the characters one by one which will increase both space and time complexity.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution using `rstrip()` to remove trailing letters and underscores, which I consider a pretty smart alternative to `re.sub()` as used in other answers:

```
import string

s = '111_Joe_Smith_2010_Assessment'
new_s = s.rstrip(f'{string.ascii_letters}_')  # For Python 3.6+
new_s = s.rstrip(string.ascii_letters+'_')    # For other Python versions

print(new_s) # 111_Joe_Smith_2010
```

Comment: Sorry, that 's because I have used the beautiful f-strings that are available only in Python 3.6+. I updated my post to add an alternative for other versions of Python.